# Using GD w/imagecache vs. imagecache_optimize or imagecache_smushit

Tags: performance, media

My understanding of PHP GD is that when it writes a file, no meta information is included.

If that's the case, is there any specific advantage to running imagecache_optimize or imagecache_smushit in addition to using GD as the selected API?  And if so, is the improvement more than negligible?

Comment: Just wondering, are you going to be running a very photo-heavy site? Because unless you're going to process more than a few photos per second, this could possibly be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: This is for an existing website that has a relatively large number of editors who may be uploading any number of images at any given time. I wouldn't call it image heavy by any means.

Comment: In that case, it really depends on the photos being uploaded. If you have a lot of PNGs, the difference will likely be greater. If its mostly JPEG files saved from programs like Aperture or Photoshop, I don't think it will squeeze out too much more data (unless you're resizing by a large amount)... Anyways, it's very use-case specific, and you'll have to test to see if it's more than just a marginal improvement.